# jackson fasterxml multiple elements with the same name

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jackson

I need to generate XML that confirms to this XSD:

`<xsd:element name="Line" type="Line" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="3"/>`

So that the output is like:

```
<root>
    <Line>A</Line>
    <Line>B</Line>
    <Line>C</Line>
</root>
```

The problem is that if I annotate the variables in the Java bean like:

```
@JsonProperty("Line")
private String Line1;

@JsonProperty("Line")
private String Line2;

@JsonProperty("Line")
private String Line3;
```

Then I get an exception and if I use a `List` then the output comes out wrong, like:

```
   <root>
       <Line>
           <Line>1 New Orchard Road</Line>
           <Line>Armonk</Line>
       </Line>
   </root>
```

With a parent `<Line>` element in excess. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I guess you should try `private List<String> line` or `private String[] line` instead of using three different fields.

Comment: Doesn't work. As mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ah, I missed that "`Line`" in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need is the proper jackson annotation:

```
public class ListTest
{
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    public List<String> line = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper(module);
    ListTest lt = new ListTest();
    lt.line.add("A");
    lt.line.add("B");
    lt.line.add("C");
    try {
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, lt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:

```
<ListTest><line>A</line><line>B</line><line>C</line></ListTest>
```